# How to remove __metadata from OData v2 responses

Tags: odata

I can see that OData v4 has support for reducing the metadata/urls that get returned, but I was wondering if OData v2 supports anything.  I cannot see anything in the spec, but not sure if I just missed it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, OData v2 simply does not have a lightweight JSON serialization.